# find the coefficient of $ x^{32}$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^{12})^{5}$.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

find the coefficient of $ x^{32}$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^{12})^{5}$.
is there some thick for this question? because It's busy to calculate by multiple polynomial 5 times and get the answer. and all I know is the coefficient of $x^n$ is equal to the coefficient of $x^{60-n}$

Comment: how about $(1-x^{13})^5(1-x)^{-5}$

Comment: Do you know about the multinomial theorem?

Comment: I think @SandipanDey that expressing it as $(1-x)^{-5} \cdot (1-x^{13})^5$ is best ;-). We only need the fist three terms of the second part, and it means we get the sum of $1,-5,10$ times the corresponding factorials from the $(1-x)^{-5}$..

Comment: Try this one. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309184/number-of-integer-solutions-of-a-linear-equation-under-constraints